# Display byte array as hex string in Neo4j Browser

Tags: neo4j

Is it possible to show data in hex format if I stored data as byte array using Neo4j Browser?
It is 16 bytes of md5 sum.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this ...

```
MATCH (n:YourNodeLabel)
RETURN apoc.convert.toHex(n.yourByteArrayProperty) AS hexValue
```

I've created a  [hex-ORDPATH](https://github.com/waigitdas/Neo4j-Genealogy-PlugIns/blob/main/java%20classes/graph/ordpath.java) in a Neo4j user defined function (UDF). That code might help if you want to write a custom UDF.